# Error importing dask library python

Tags: python, dask

I am getting started with `dask` and `dask_ml`. I have had no issues performing simple operations with `dask` but have been unable to successfully `import dask_ml`.  The installation of the library was successful. Below is the code and the error generated.

```
import dask_ml.joblib

def main():
    print("test")
main()
```

**Error**

```
UnknownExtra: dask 0.15.3 has no such extra feature 'array'
```

any suggestions on how to resolve this error?
I have attempted uninstalling and re-installing dask and dask_ml using both pip install and conda install.

Comment: That is incorrect indentation

Comment: Which version of dask-ml are you using? I'm guessing your dask-ml version is not compatible with dask itself. You may want to try and upgrade dask (to 0.18.2).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My dask is already on 0.18.2, and I am assuming my dask_ml is on 0.15.3, given the error. I will try to upgrade the dask_ml to 0.18.2

Comment: Unfortunately, my dask_ml will not update beyond it's current version.